# Transparent activity that really clear other Activities

Tags: android, transparent

I have a small android machine that has android and other native process at same time.
Because the graphic of native is below, android app should be transparent.
I read many sources, made transparent activity and it works.

But it is special app for my machine, thus it should act like Launcher.
The thing is... if I back to my app after launch another app, the screen still shows another app's image.

Ex: My app(Home) - Other non-transparent app - (back/home) - My app shows previous other app's image, because my app is transparent.
So I want to make my app to clear all screens and be transparent to show native's graphic. I don't mean finish others. I want to clear or turn off visibility of other apps only.

FYI, I can't wrap the native to android app with JNI. The native process is old and big legacy. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER`. Setting that to your activity will make it seem like all other apps were closed/hidden:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER

Comment: Thanks. I tried that flag but the wallpaper is not transparent. Even I set transparent .png image with WallpaperManager. So I can't see the native graphics.